# Using XNA's MediaLibrary in WinForms app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xna

I am trying to use MediaLibrary class in my Windows Forms application. I have referened all required Microsoft.Xna. dll's and I have put all my using's in there.

I can access everything else in Xna. I have added `using Microsoft.Xna; using Microsoft.Xna.Framework; using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;`

However it seems as though the only thing I **can't** access after all of this is the MediaLibrary class.

How can I access it in Windows Forms.

Below is what I mean by "can't access":

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "can't access"?

Comment: Oh, I mean I just can't use the class. It just comes up with a red squiggly and when I try to use it like this (using MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary()) { /*...*/ } It just gives me options to "Generate new class" or "Generate new type", etc. I can't access any properties/methods/anything inside of it at all.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. As a workaround, you may try to add [`MonoGame.Framework`](http://www.monogame.net/downloads/) dlls instead. XNA is deprecated and not supported anymore since a while, MonoGame is the open-source implementation of it. You can access `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary` from MonoGame. Actually, it's almost vanilla XNA.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to declare your MediaLibrary with the fully qualified name instead of the `using` statement (e.g. Microsoft.[...].Media.MediaLibrary) or use intellisense to check which classes are available from your Framework.Media.